# Is there any way to List the list views size in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am new to flutter and trying to develop a version updation software. I need to show the version in a radio list. Is there any way to contain the list view in a container? Currently the list view is overflowing through the other widgets. I need to contain the list view between the text and the button. Is there any way to do it.The code the screenshot is given below

[![screenshot][1]][1]

````
Widget _createVersionRadioTiles(List<String> versions) {
    var radioTiles = <Widget>[];
    for (var version in versionList) {
      var tile = Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: RadioListTile<String>(
          selected: selectedVersion == version,
          tileColor: colorDarkGray,
          // selectedTileColor: Colors.white,
          value: version,
          groupValue: selectedVersion,
          onChanged: (String? value) {
            setState(() {
              selectedVersion = value!.toString();
            });
          },
          title: Text(version),
        ),
      );

      radioTiles.add(tile);
    }
    return Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 500,
          width: 500,
          child: ListView(children: radioTiles),
        )
      ],
    );
  } ```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQxns.jpg
````

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the RadioListTile with a Card widget. It will contain the ListTile in the container.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `SizedBox` with `Container`, and use `clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge` to remove the overflows. see code below:

```
return Column(
  children: [
    Container(
      height: 500,
      width: 500,
      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
      child: ListView(children: radioTiles),
    )
  ],
);
```

Comment: Nop. Its not working. Same issue again.